# R: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the correlation between two stocks in R:

```
library(quantmod)
tickers = c("CAT", "AAPL")
stocks = getSymbols(tickers, auto.assign=TRUE)
plot(as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(CAT))),as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(AAPL)))
      ,xlab="CAT",ylab="AAPL",main="Scatterplot of CAT vs AAPL Daily Returns")
```

but I get the error "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths differ" -- how do I resolve this?

Comment: My hunch is that **the lengths of x (as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(CAT)))) and y (as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(AAPL)))) differ**. Also, it is impossible to help you without knowing what these two variables are (what is getSymbols?).

Comment: getSymbols is from the quantmod package.

Comment: I didn't get an error so I cannot be of much help. Could be platform or versions dependent problems (and you have described neither.) I'm using R 3.0.2 quantmod 0.4-0 and it on OSX 10.7.5

Comment: So, what have you tried to understand what these two 'x' and 'y' variables were? Here is what I would type:
**x <- as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(CAT)))** and **y <- as.numeric(dailyReturn(Ad(AAPL)))**. Then, have a look at **length(x)**, **length(y)**, **summary(x)**, **summary(y)**... Does it fit what you would like them to be?

Comment: The loading message suggested there was new information to read about modifications to `getSymbols`:"Version 0.4-0 included new data defaults. See ?getSymbols." And to Jealie: Trying to help when you don't even have the code running seems fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the quantmod package in order to execute your code.  But after doing that and executing you code exactly as written, I got the following image.  Am I correct that this is the image you were hoping to get?

If so, my guess is that one your packages is out of date.  I would type `update.packages()` from the R console and try again.  Can you report back if that fixed your issue?

[image: Scatterplot]